# Debugging partial GStreamer pipeline stall

Tags: python, gstreamer

I have a rather complex GStreamer pipeline, with several WebRTC endpoints that can dynamically connect and disconnect, thereby also influencing other internal bits of the pipeline plumbing.

Generally, this works fine, but I do still have occasional hangs where some parts of the pipeline just stop delivering data downstream. This occurs *sometimes* after disconnecting a client - I've already used the leaks tracer to verify that I'm not leaving any dangling pads or similar floating around. The pipeline graph in that semi-stalled state also looks perfectly normal.

I'm a bit stumped about how to proceed further. Looking at GST_DEBUG at various levels hasn't gotten me anywhere either (maybe due to sheer volume). Any suggestions for debug filters or tracers I could use here, and also ideas/tools for parsing the massive amount of output?

I had also given gst-debugger a try in the meantime, but if I connect the debugger to my pipeline when a webrtcbin is present, the pipeline process segfaults.